# Decoding base64 from xml which also has lz4 compression

Tags: xml, base64, lz4

This is my first post so apologies if what I am asking isn't allowed, I am not a programmer by any means I am a user who has an xml file which contains data which is seemingly encoded in base64 but also compressed using lz4. Below is a sample of one of the lines which I would like to decode and decompress to show the data: -

<BeadTableMaterial_Array coding="base64" compression="lz4">VDIeHh4yAQBBFBQeFAEANDIjIxQADwIAx1AyMjIyMg==</BeadTableMaterial_Array>

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The whole xml file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qtpVCk3gy-t4jCPhLE6bgTqjdH38ScgH/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Which language/application are you using to process this XML?

Comment: @kimbert I am viewing this in UltraEdit. I want to analyse the data contained within this file in an access database that I have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Copy and paste the contents of the tag `<BeadTableMaterial_Array>` into a new file `BeadTableMaterial_Array.base64`
2. Use any publicly-available tool to decode the file `BeadTableMaterial_Array.base64`. Call the result `BeadTableMaterial_Array.lz4`
3. Use any publicly-available compression utility (e.g. pkzip) to decompress the file `BeadTableMaterial_Array.lz4`.

I assume you only need to do this once. If not, you will need to put all of that into some kind of script or program.